# On the definition of positive variation of a signed measure: is $\mu^+(E) = \max(\mu(E),0)?$

Tags: measure-theory

In Rudin's book, Real and Complex analysis, given a real signed measure $\mu$, Rudin does define the positive variation of $\mu$ as: $\mu^+(E) =\frac{1}{2}(|\mu|(E)+\mu(E) ), E \in \mathcal A.$ Well, for real functions $f$, we also know that $f^+ =\max(f,0).$ Is it also true for charges? That is, does $\mu^+ = \max(\mu,0)?$ If so, why one would not define the positive variation like this?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

For a real function, we define $f^+ = \max(f,0)$ pointwise.  Since $\mu$ is a function on a $\sigma$-algebra of sets, the corresponding "pointwise" definition of $\nu = \max(\mu,0)$ would probably be $\nu(A) = \max(\mu(A),0)$?

However, in this case, $\nu$ is not necessarily a measure on that same $\sigma$-algebra of sets, so it's not a "good" definition.

---

The connection between the positive part of a real function $f$ and the positive variation of a signed measure $\mu$ is more closely given by the following:

> If $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R},m)$ for a measure $m$ and $\mu$ is a signed measure given by $\mu(A) = \int_A f\,dm,$ then $\mu^+(A) = \int_A f^+\,dm.$